# Need to send mail from my server and also from a 3rd party provider

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, spf, zoho

Is it possible to send mail from two valid sources?

To expand on this, I run an online shop web app, to separate concerns (and servers) I'm now using a 3rd party to handle mailboxes, (zoho.com) so as you can imagine, my mx records point to their provided names, and spf looks as follows: `v=spf1 mx include:zoho.com ~all` everything with zoho works smoothly.

Now, at the end of each day we need to notify each of our customers about their orders, plus other various automated mails during the day.

These mails come from the server, and are all sent using PHPMailer, but knowingly not using SMTP because I would very quickly fill zoho's queues and quotas for outgoing mail.

And more importantly, I cannot don't receive mail from my own domain sent from the server, but all other users seem to get the server produced mails just fine.

So the question is, what can I do to make my server a verified sender for my domain without removing zoho of course, some change in the SPF?

Comment: Yes, you need to include the additional valid email source in your SPF. But StackOverflow is a programming Q&A site. If you want help on this within the StackExchange network, I'd recommend posing this question on http://ServerFault.com/, though there are also plenty of excellent SPF resources on the web, which you can find using your favourite search engine.

Answer (score 2):

You can include multiple domain names, and your `~all` should be `-all`

```
v=spf1 mx include:zoho.com include:myotherdomain.com -all
```

Comment: I was aware of multiple domains inside the spf, I don't know why I had my mind set as if when mails were being sent from a server no domain name is used but only and IP address, I'll wait for dns changes to propagate and check if the issue gets fixed by this.

Comment: The default action should only be `-all` if you're not using DMARC.

Comment: My mind was set on a SPF error, but the actual problem was the MTA settings withing my server, where my domain was registered as a local domain instead of remotes, hence mail never even leaving the server in the first place. Still this helped me have a valid SPF record.

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem here was the MTA settings with Exim, where my own domain name was set as a localdomain, hence the mail wasn't even leaving the server, by changing it to remotedomain mails started working normally.